# MPI code error check

Tags: c, mpi

I have a piece of code, unfortunately, I couldn't run it, but I was trying to find if it has an error logically. Or if there is something missing, here is the

**code:**

```
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int numtasks, rank, dest, source, rc, count, tag=1;
    char inmsg, outmsg=’x’;
    MPI_Status Stat;
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    if (rank == 0) {
        dest = 1;
        source = 1;
        rc = MPI_Send(&outmsg, 1, MPI_CHAR, dest, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        rc = MPI_Recv(&inmsg, 1, MPI_CHAR, source, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Stat);
    }
    else if (rank == 1) {
        dest = 0;
        source = 0;
        rc = MPI_Send(&outmsg, 1, MPI_CHAR, dest, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        rc = MPI_Recv(&inmsg, 1, MPI_CHAR, source, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Stat);
    }

    rc = MPI_Get_count(&Stat, MPI_CHAR, &count);
    printf("Task %d: Received %d char(s) from task %d with tag %d \n",
    rank, count, Stat.MPI_SOURCE, Stat.MPI_TAG);
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

And, is it allowed to save MPI send and receive in a variable, here rc has been used?

Comment: Please format your code so that it is more legible. Beyond making it more likely that someone will answer your question, formatting your code also has the benefit of making it clearer to yourself what the code does.

Comment: "Unfortunately I couldn't run it" - Are you getting an error when you run it? Are you unable to compile it? Do you not have access to a machine with MPI installed on it?

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll I have no more access at the system where I ran MPI codes, so I couldn't run this one. But I wanted just to know if it is correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is wrong. It contains a deadlock, which means that it can hang forever or misbehave otherwise. `MPI_Send` is a blocking operation - it may block until the respective `MPI_Recv` is called. So both processes will be stuck at their respective `MPI_Send` operation before `MPI_Recv` is called. Use `MPI_Sendrecv` instead.

Note that due to optimizations, MPI may instead chose to send the data immediately for small messages, so the code may complete even though it is wrong. Do not rely on that!

Normally, you don't have to check MPI return codes, as errors are fatal in MPI by default. In particular, don't assign the return code without checking it for `MPI_SUCCESS`.

Note that you can easily install MPI on any system, e.g. OpenMPI is available for most Linux distributions. There is no reason not to play around with MPI on a normal desktop system.